# Charactor Encoding non standard charactors into HTML

Tags: character-encoding, special-characters

I have a lot of text files containing articles. I don't know how to call the problem I'm facing. Something like this, the letter 'o'(call normal) and 'о'(call awkward) are different letters. Trust me, they might look the same in some fonts but would have different representation in some other fonts and this drives me crazy.

I tried to convert the letter 'o'(normal) to HTML entity and I got 'o' as a result but when I did that with the letter 'о'(awkward), the result would be `&#1086`. Now, I have to delete these characters and retype the new ones to solve the problem.

How could I standardize these awkward characters back to normal faster?

I can't do it manually because it's not only one 'o' but many other characters as well, say 'а', 'еѕе', 'ѕе', 'ѕ', 'іѕ', etc,.

My English is not good. I'm sorry if there are any misspellings. I'm not sure about the title too. Somebody might help me to modify it. Thanks

Comment: This area is called Character Encoding. Best place to start is the Wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding

To undo the changes you made can you not just do a simple find replace?

Comment: `&#1086;` is a correct way of representing a Cyrillic small letter o in HTML.  It will appear as a Cyrillic small letter o on the page.  What is the actual problem that you trying to solve?

Comment: It looks ugly in my current font. I want to convert it to the Latin letter so it will display properly. Is there any way to find and replace all of these automatically? Doing that manually is really time-consuming.

Answer (score 1):

The character о that you call “awkward” is U+043E CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER O, and `&#1086;` is one way of representing it using an HTML character reference. It is treated as distinct from the Latin letter o, even though the characters have identical glyphs in any font that contains both (at least in all fonts I have seen). But if you declare a font that does not contrain Cyrillic letters, then the two characters will (usually) look different, since they will be taken from different fonts. (The Cyrillic letter is then taken from some browser-dependent fallback font.)

The conclusions depend on the context where the characters appear. If Cyrillic letters appear in words intentionally written in them (say, a Russian word in a document that discusses the Russian language), then they should of course not be “fixed”. Instead, you should try and find a suitable font that contains them.

If Cyrillic letters appear due to some technical errors (e.g., data entry errors) and you know they should be replaced by Latin letters, do so. How you do this depends on the authoring environment and isn’t really an HTML issue at all. Typically, you can use a global search and replace command, and you might find a tool that checks for “unusual” characters in a file so that you will know which characters need to be fixed (e.g. my simple [character frequency analyzer](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/charcount.html8)).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are facing here is a problem with Encoding, you need to open your files in a text editor and change the encoding to UTF-8.
If you have Notepad++ just click on Encoding and than click on convert to UTF-8.

Comment: Hi. I thought of that and tried to do that but not work.